# How to serve multiple domains which share the application back-end in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, web-applications

I have two web domains, call them alpha.com and beta.com. I want to run two different public facing websites on these two different domains, but from a shared server and within the same flask app and application context. These websites will both share the backend app and database,

My current project structure is below:

```
app/
  -static/
    --alphacom_static/
    --betacom_static/
    --shared_backend_static/
  -blueprints/
    --alphacom_frontend_bluprint/
    --betacom_frontend_blueprint/
    --shared_backend_blueprint/
```

I'm serving beta.com running on localhost with flask/gevent through a reverse proxy on the server. I plan to just add a blueprint for alpha.com.

The route of the beta.com landing page is `@blueprint.route(r'/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`. When a user logs in at beta.com/login then they get directed to beta.com/app.

What is the approach using blueprints and routes, to bring alpha.com as a blueprint and when user logs in they are served alpha.com/app?

How can I modify the routes for alpha.com to avoid a collision with beta.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it is not very well supported in flask's current stable release of `Flask==0.12.2`. It theoretically can be done to a degree with [host_matching](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/routing/#host-matching). But in my testing, the static routes were always broken.

However, the flask development version on master at the time of writing has merged a pull request that makes it a little easier. Doing a `pip install git+git://github.com/pallets/flask.git` will install `Flask==0.13.dev0`. Then, using the factory pattern to create the flask app, you can set `host_matching=True` and `static_host=127.0.0.1:8000` in my case.

For me, my factory function looks like this:

```
def create_app(config_obj=None):
    """An application factory, as explained here:
    http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appfactories/.
    :param config_object: The configuration object to use.
    """
    app = Flask(__name__, host_matching=True, static_host='127.0.0.1:8000')
    app.config.from_object(config_obj)
    register_extensions(app)
    register_blueprints(app)
    return app
```

Another thing needed to make this work is to modify your hosts and set the domains you'd like to reference in the host file. On windows, this is found at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. At the bottom of the hosts file, I've modified as such:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       alpha.local
    127.0.0.1       beta.local
    127.0.0.1       local
```

You need to run this solution behind a reverse proxy (NGINX on Linux or IIS on Windows) and set it up to forward the appropriate requests to `alpha.local:8000` or `beta.local:8000` in the case of this example. But, you will modify `<subdomain>.local:<port>` based on your actual need.

Another issue you will deal with is browser complaining about CORS requests, so you may need to set headers for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or specific domains like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://beta.local:8000`. For development server, I found this helpful for CORS to allow font access:

```
@blueprint.after_app_request
def add_headers_to_fontawesome_static_files(response):
    """
    Fix for font-awesome files: after Flask static send_file() does its
    thing, but before the response is sent, add an
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    HTTP header to the response (otherwise browsers complain).
    """
    if not os.environ.get('APP_ENV') == 'prod':
        if request.path and re.search(r'\.(ttf|woff|woff2|svg|eot)$', request.path):
            response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        return response
```

Note that for production, you must set your modified headers on your proxy (like NGINX or IIS) and the above function is not useful for produciton.

Last, with `host_matching=True` then the routes must be specified for hosts, example being below:

```
@blueprint.route('/about/', methods=['GET', 'POST'],
                 host='<string:subdom>.local:8000')
def about_app(**kwargs):
    """The about page."""
    return render_template('about.html')
```

If you do the routes as above, it is helpful to set the url_defualts in a function somewhere in your app, like below:

```
@blueprint.app_url_defaults
def add_subdom(endpoint, values):
    path = request.url_root
    if 'alpha.local' in path:
        g.subdom = 'alpha'
    elif 'beta.local' in path:
        g.subdom = 'beta'
    if current_app.url_map.is_endpoint_expecting(endpoint, 'subdom'):
        values['subdom'] = g.subdom
```

Good luck, this was not easy.